# NGN detection with Asterisk PBX

Tags: asterisk, telephony, telephone

Is it possible to detect if a NGN (Non Geographic Number, e.g. 0844, 0845, 0870 etc) number has been used to connect to an Asterisk PBX?

Thanks in advance.

Kyle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asterisk can only act on the information provided by the call. If your telephony service provider delivers the calling number (CallerID or ANI) via PRI, SIP, or other signalling, then Asterisk can act on that data. Whether you can trust the validity of the provided data has nothing to do with Asterisk; it can be spoofed.

Use Asterisk dialplan in extensions.conf to compare ${CALLERID(num)} against a fixed list or database, then take whatever action you wish as a result -- go to a different context, set a billing code, etc.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how your Asterisk box receives those calls.

If using E1/T1 you usually receive a DNIS indication with the called number, available on your receiving context.

If receiving those calls trough some SIP provider, they should provide you some way to access that data.